# Select alt attribute of a images

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have

```
   <div id="aa">
   <img src="." height="17" alt="example1" title="">
       <table>
            <tbody><tr>
              <th></th>
              <td></td>
       </tbody>
       </table>


   <img src="." height="17" alt="example2" title="">
       <table>
            <tbody><tr>
              <th></th>
              <td></td>
       </tbody>
       </table>


   <img src="." height="17" alt="example3" title="">
       <table>
            <tbody><tr>
              <th></th>
              <td></td>
       </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
```

I only want to select the attributes "alt" values "example1, example2, example3" of images. How can I get them.

Comment: Please provide the code you have used to do that till now.

Comment: If you are completely new to this domain then I suggest you to learn javaScript or jQuery.

Comment: your question is not clear.. describe briefly with full code..

Answer (score 18):

I presume you mean that you want to select all the images (in CSS) that contain `example*` in the alt attribute, so you can style them. (and that you don't mean that you actually want tot select the text set in the alt attribute)

You can use the attribute selector:

```
img[alt~="example"] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, if the answer suits you, please mark it as solution (v-mark on the left of it)

Answer (score 12):

To select some attribute use selector `img[alt="example1"], img[alt="example2"], img[alt="example3"]`